# My car is Going inside the terrain how to Stop it in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When ever I start my game I have a car and the scene and the car is on the terrain and the car goes through the terrain. How to stop this from happening and make the car move on the terrain without going through it?

1. On car I have RigidBody with **use Gravity** set to **true**, and I have a BoxCollider with **Is Trigger** set to **false**
2. On terrain I have a RigidBody with **use Gravity** set to **false**, and a MeshCollider with **Convex** set to **false**

Comment: Use LICEcap to record and show what's exactly happening in the scene view.

Comment: Why does the terrain have a rigidbody? How are you moving the car?